# JBPM : Trigger business process when there is a message in Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, jbpm

I have come across Kafka WorkItem for JBPM (7.18.0) for publishing message to a kafka topic.

But how can i trigger a particular workflow when there is a message in topic.

or how can the process resume if there is a message in the topic

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the only code in there is a producer, not a consumer

https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm-work-items/tree/master/kafka-workitem/src/main/java/org/jbpm/process/workitem/kafka

I suppose the workaround for this would be write your own consumer, and stick it within a generic Java action, but that would need to be in an infinite polling loop, ideally in a separate thread within the process itself, so I'm not sure how it'll work for triggering later actions